# TKInter GUI appearance containing Notebook changes when I change class name but not parameters

Tags: python, class, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to make application with Notebook Tabs, but each tab should be described separately as class. For start I gave 2 classnames for 2 tabs as Frame1 and Frame2, but I want to give sensible names.
Here is the code that works:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Title')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.Frame1 = Frame(container)
        self.Frame1.config(bg='blue')
        self.Frame1.place(x=0, y=24, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.9)


class Frame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.Frame2 = Frame(container)
        self.Frame2.config(height=200, width=203, bg= 'green')
        self.Frame2.place(x=0, y=24)

Frame1 = Frame1(notebook)
notebook.add(Frame1, text = "Connection")

Frame2 = Frame2(notebook)
notebook.add(Frame2, text = "Transient Response")

notebook.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result is on screenshot - 2 tabs with blue and green filling.
I want to give sensible names. As soon as I change class name, e.g. Frame2 for Frame3, picture spoils (see screenshot).

Comment: Your screenshot didn't get attached, so I'm not sure what "spoils" is supposed to mean, but there are some obvious problems with this code.  In particular, your `Frame1` object (for example) *is* a Frame, but it also creates an entirely separate Frame named `self.Frame1`.  The former is what you actually add to your notebook, but the latter is what you're setting the color of.  You either need to get rid of this extra Frame completely, or make it contained by the actual Frame in the notebook (`Frame(self)` instead of `Frame(container)`).

Comment: I don't see screenshots. I don't understand what you want to do. I don't know what makes problem with "sensible names"

Comment: BWT: if I would have to use inner frame then I would use the same name `self.frame` in both classes instead of `self.Frame1` and `self.Frame2` - and for me this is `"sensible name"`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating a frame inside your frame classes. Instances of `Frame1` and `Frame2` are already frames. And if you do add a frame inside of `Frame1` and `Frame2`, they need to be children of `self`, not `container`.

Also, you're using the name `Frame1` both for the name of the class and the instance of the class. You should not do that. You should name the instance with a lowercase first letter according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container, bg='blue')

frame1 = Frame1(notebook)
```

Note that the instance of `Frame1` is itself a frame just like any other frame. If you want to configure any of the attributes, you can do so like in my example where I set the background when calling `super`, but you can also call the `configure` method on `self` at any time:

```
class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container, bg='blue')
        self.configure(width=200, height=200)
```

You can also configure it outside the class just like you can with any other widget:

```
frame1 = Frame1(notebook)
...
frame1.configure(background="bisque")
```

Comment: Thanks for responce! But if I do not create new frames inside frame classes, how can I set frame(tab) size and background colour, preferably different for each frame(tab)?

Comment: @Ivan_ if yo don't create inner frame then you will need `self.config(bg='blue')` instead of `self.Frame1.config(bg='blue')`. And `self.config(height=200, width=203, bg= 'green')` instead of `self.Frame2.config(height=200, width=203, bg= 'green')`

Comment: @Furas, thanks, it works! Just tried.